# Google Cloud SQL failback after manually triggering failover

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to revert a manually triggered failover in the Google Cloud SQL service.

I'm using a second generation MySQL 5.7 server. After manually triggering the failover the data center zone updated shortly after as expected. I'm unsure how to now revert back to the original data center zone. Updating the configuration settings with the original zone does not work. Do I simply just have to trigger another failover and hope it goes back to the original zone?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that triggering another failover reverts it back to the original zone and also removes the failover messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform manual fail-over you need to perform a fallback operation , this means that you need to perform a manual fail-over again, this action will return your database to the original zone.

There are more infromation [about how Fail-over works on Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-overview)